# transpose DBObject to json

Tags: java, json, mongodb

I have a list of mongo db objects List from mongo fetch

for example the DBObject contains column name and order:

```
student name,1
student id,2
student address,3
```

I would like to transpose this data for datatables ui to json like so:

```
   [
        { title: "student name" },
        { title: "student id" },
        { title: "student address" }
   ]
```

I looked up GSON lib but it seems like i need to add annotations to my objects - no intentions of doing so.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose you have your Pojo like this:

```
class YourPojo {
    private String title;
    public String getTitle() {
        return title;
    }
    public void setTitle(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }
}
```

You can build Gson json:

```
final JsonArray datasets = new JsonArray();
for (String key: dbObject.keySet()) {
    JsonObject dataset = new JsonObject();
    dataset.addProperty("title", key);
    datasets.add(dataset);
}
```

And then convert it  to  your pojo:

```
Type listType = new TypeToken<ArrayList<YourPojo>>(){}.getType();
List<YourPojo> yourPojoList = new Gson().fromJson(datasets, listType);
```